ggplot2: geom_line with color and linetype rendered
I want to plot a line graph with two categorical variables. The desired output is that
'team' variable is rendered as color, while each 'strength' is rendered with a different linetype. So the colored lines for each team has different linetypes based on strength on the same line.
My code:
tribble(
    ~game_seconds, ~xg, ~team, ~strength,
    1, .2, "team1", "equal",
    1, .2, "team2", "equal",
    2, .8, "team1", "equal",
    2, .2, "team2", "equal",
    3, .8, "team1", "short_handed",
    3, .5, "team2", "power_play",
    4, .8, "team1", "short_handed",
    4, .6, "team2", "power_play",
    5, .9, "team1", "equal",
    5, .6, "team2", "equal",
) |>
    ggplot(aes(x = game_seconds, y = xg)) +
    geom_line(aes(color = team, linetype = strength)) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c(
        "team1" = "steelblue",
        "team2" = "tomato2"
    )) +
    scale_linetype_manual(values = c(
        "equal" = "solid",
        "short_handed" = "dotted",
        "power_play" = "dashed"
    )) +
    theme_minimal()

This is rendered like this (not like desired)

The desired is more like this (colored lines are correct, but between the blue line should be dotted between 3 and 4 and tomato line dashed)

Any ideas to solve this? I appreciate your help, thanks.

I think you need geom_segment.

Thanks. Yes that's a good idea @zx8754

This one way of doing it as suggested by @zx8754 using geom_segment
Although I feel there is probably a neater way to allocate the linetype grouping variable.
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df1 <- tribble(
  ~game_seconds, ~xg, ~team, ~strength,
  1, .2, "team1", "equal",
  1, .2, "team2", "equal",
  2, .8, "team1", "equal",
  2, .2, "team2", "equal",
  3, .8, "team1", "short_handed",
  3, .5, "team2", "power_play",
  4, .8, "team1", "short_handed",
  4, .6, "team2", "power_play",
  5, .9, "team1", "equal",
  5, .6, "team2", "equal",
)


df1 <- 
  df1 |> 
  mutate(x_end = lead(game_seconds, default = last(game_seconds)),
         y_end = lead(xg, default = last(xg)),
         ln_type = ifelse(game_seconds == 4, lead(strength), strength),
         .by = team)

  
ggplot(df1, aes(x = game_seconds, y = xg, xend = x_end, yend = y_end)) +
  geom_segment(aes(color = team, linetype = ln_type)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("team1" = "steelblue",
                                "team2" = "tomato2" )) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("equal" = "solid",
                                   "short_handed" = "dotted",
                                   "power_play" = "dashed"))


Created on 2024-06-11 with reprex v2.0.2

Peter's answer is perfect. To be make the code a bit more generic I changed the mutate for the linetype:
df1 <- df1 |>
    mutate(
        x_end = lead(game_seconds, default = last(game_seconds)),
        y_end = lead(xg, default = last(xg)),
        ln_type = ifelse(game_seconds == max(game_seconds) - 1,
                         lead(strength), strength),
        .by = team
    )

